# When creating a 'new column' in a Power BI table, can my dax formula run a comparison with all rows of another (small) table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a large (live) table in Power BI which includes easting/northing location data.  (Eastings and northings are distances in metres from a fixed origin, so form an x-y grid).

I also have a smaller table with a finite number (~20) of fixed locations in easting/northing format.

I'd like to add a column in the large table to show the distance to the closest point in the smaller table.  (This is done using Pythagoras: sqrt(Δeasting²+Δnorthing²)).

Any help with this would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit - example data:

**large_table**

| eastlarge | northlarge |
| --- | --- |
| 104 | 103 |
| 205 | 212 |
| 209 | 240 |
| 328 | 345 |

**small_table**

| eastsmall | northsmall |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 |
| 200 | 200 |
| 300 | 300 |

I can manually calculate the new column in large_table, but obviously I need to implement a formula:

**large_table**

| eastlarge | northlarge | min_distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 103 | 5 |
| 205 | 212 | 13 |
| 209 | 240 | 41 |
| 328 | 345 | 53 |

Comment: Interesting problm, please provide some test data of the two tables, inc. column names. It can be done in DAX as well as Powerquery.

Comment: I've added sample data above, but it isn't showing it correctly for some reason.  I hope it is still legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a calculated column:

```
Minimum Distance = 
VAR _easting = large_table[eastlarge]
VAR _northing = large_table[northlarge]
RETURN
MINX ( 
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 
        small_table ,
        "dist" , SQRT ( ( small_table[eastsmall] - _easting )^2 + ( small_table[northsmall] - _northing )^2 )
    ),
    [dist]
)
```

Result:

[image]

You can also use a measure, using the same code with small adjustments:

```
Min Distance := 
VAR _easting = SELECTEDVALUE ( large_table[eastlarge] )
VAR _northing = SELECTEDVALUE ( large_table[northlarge] )
RETURN
MINX ( 
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 
        small_table ,
        "dist" , SQRT ( ( small_table[eastsmall] - _easting )^2 + ( small_table[northsmall] - _northing )^2 )
    ),
    [dist]
)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  I independently found MINX, so it's good to have it confirmed that this is the correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in power query.
First generate a table combining both large and small tables.
[image]
Then create a calculate column 'distance'
[image]
Then group by using summerize function
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach and a little different from what I've settled on.  I like the idea of GENERATE, so I'll bear that in mind in future.

Comment: If it is useful, accept the answer. You accepted different answer.